# Is it possible to render the color of data-src image in ParticleSlider?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

people I have created a slider in particle slider js and now I want to render the data-src image color like android logo can be displayed in green particles? here I have used particle Slider is it possible to achieve this?

here is the code.

```
<body id="particle-slider">
<div class="slides">
<div id="first-slide" class="slide" data-src="../canvas/images/lgCrssn.png" />
</div>


<div id="second-slide" class="slide" data-src="../canvas/images/290px-Sony_Alpha_logo.svg.png" />
</div>
</div>
<canvas class="draw"></canvas>
<script>
var init = function(){
    var isMobile = navigator.userAgent &&
            navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mobile') >= 0;
    var isSmall = window.innerWidth < 1000;

    var ps = new ParticleSlider({
        slideDelay: 10,
        mouseForce: 1000,
        monochrome: true,
        showArrowControls: true,
        ptlGap: 2,
        ptlSize: 2
    });



    (window.addEventListener
            ? window.addEventListener('click', function(){ps.init(true)}, false)
            : window.onclick = function(){ps.init(true)});
}

var initParticleSlider = function(){

    var psScript = document.createElement('script');
    (psScript.addEventListener
            ? psScript.addEventListener('load', init, false)
            : psScript.onload = init);
    psScript.src = 'js/particleSlider.js';
    psScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.body.appendChild(psScript);
}




(window.addEventListener
        ? window.addEventListener('load', initParticleSlider, false)
        : window.onload = initParticleSlider);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes!** It's possible to achieve this. All you have to do is, set the `monochrome` to `false` :)

```
var ps = new ParticleSlider({
    slideDelay: 10,
    mouseForce: 1000,
    monochrome: false, //<-- this
    showArrowControls: true,
    ptlGap: 2,
    ptlSize: 2
});
```

Comment: you are legend man!! superb I have searched like hell in API documentation for this thing :(

Comment: thank you also there is one more issue I've set showArrowControls to true and still arrows are not showing

Comment: um.. I'm not aware of that.. will inspect in a moment

Comment: Mm.. yeah sure.. :)

Comment: hey have you found anything? coz I haven't got anything yet.. :(

Comment: um.. I don't think it visually displays any controls. Maybe, you'd have to create it manually :/

Comment: oh.. any better reference do you have? because in API documentation there is nothing like that..